# for all $n \in \mathbb N f(n) \leq 7 \cdot 5^n - 3^n$, also $f(n) \leq c \cdot 5^n$

Tags: induction

[image]

Base Case:

Let n = 0

$f(n) = 6$ [def of f]

$\leq 7 - 1 = 6 = 7 \cdot 5^0 - 3^0 = 7 \cdot 5^n - 3^n$

as wanted

IND STEP: Let $n > 0$. Suppose $f(n) \leq 7 \cdot 5^n - 3^n$ [IH]

Trying to show: $f(n+1) \leq 7 \cdot 5^{n+1} - 3^{n+1}$

$f(n+1) = 5f(n) + 3^n$ [Definition of f; $n > 0$]

$ \leq 5 \cdot 7 \cdot 5^n - 5\cdot 3^n + 3^n$ [IH]

$ = 7 \cdot 5^{n+1} - 3^n (5-1)$ [Algebra]

$= 7 \cdot 5^{n+1} - 3^{n}(4)$

$\leq 7 \cdot 5^{n+1} - 3^{n}(3)$

$= 7 \cdot 5^{n+1} - 3^{n+1}$

as wanted

How do I find c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(n) \leq 7(5^n)-3^n \leq 7(5^n)$$

Hence you can pick $c=7$.